# db based queued mail rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, rubygems, message-queue

This may be a very simple and unnecessary question, but i'm struggling.

Ever since rails 3, the world seems to have been done with the queued_mails structure. I need a gem that's written rails 3 that intercepts MyMailer's deliver method, queues the mail into db and asks us to run a rake to dequeue and send all the mails.

Its easy to make too, but i dont want to go through with the effort since its hard to believe there are none out there for rails 3+.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
instead of using gem messages-queue
create simple mailer 

pls check railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job
script/plugin install git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git
script/generate delayed_job
rake db:migrate
rake jobs:work

mailings_controller.rb 
mailing = Mailing.find(mailing_id)
mailing.send_later(:deliver)

# or
 Delayed::Job.enqueue(MailingJob.new(params[:id]), -3, 3.days.from_now)

 lib/mailing_job.rb 


class MailingJob < Struct.new(:mailing_id)
   def perform
   mailing = Mailing.find(mailing_id)
   mailing.deliver
 end
```

end